# import tensorflow as tf ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow' >>>

Tags: python

I have installed `tensorflow` through both pip and by anaconda. It still shows this error. i am using python version 3.5.

```
import tensorflow as tf

ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Do you have both `python2.7` and `python3.5` installed?  Are you inside your anaconda environment when you run your file?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Jupyter Notebook, you can check that the Tensorflow library has been properly installed in the (base) environement with the command `!pip list` directly in a notebook cell.
If it is not in the list, then install it using the command `!pip install tensorflow` directly in a cell of the notebook.